# Why my area problem is giving wrong answer?

Tags: c

I am learning c. So, I was practicing in a online judge. I have got a logic behind the problem and submitted ans got wrong answer. What is the problem?

Problem:
Area
100 Points · Limits 1s, 512 MB

In this problem, you will be given a square which has a length of n. Co-ordinates of the square are (0,0), (n,0),(n,n),(0,n) . You need to draw 4 straight lines:

Line from (0,1) to (n,n-1)
Line from (1,0) to (n-1,n)
Line from (0,n-1) to (n,1)
Line from (1,n) to (n-1,0)
These four lines will intersect in a point (x,y) like the figure shown below.
[image]

Calculate the total area of A+B+C+D (except the four corner unit square).

Input
Input will start with an integer T. Then there will be T cases. Each case will contain one integer N. 1 <= T <= 100000
3 <= n <= 1018

Output
For each test case, print “Case x: y” without quotation marks where x is the case number and y is the required answer.

It is guaranteed that y is always an integer.

Sample
Input   Output
1
6
Case 1: 8

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>

int main()
{
    int test, i;
    scanf("%d", &test);
    for(i=0; i<test; i++)
    {
    double n, area, a,x, b1, b, s, tri, area1, area_t;
    scanf("%lf", &n);
    area= n*n;
    a=n-2;
    x=n/2;
    b1= (x-1)*(x-1) + x*x;
    b= sqrt(b1);
    s= (a+b+b)/2;
    area1= s*(s-a)*(s-b)*(s-b);
    area_t = (4* sqrt(area1));
    printf("Case %d: %.0lf\n",i+1, (area-(area_t + 4)));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Please help me to improve the code. Thank you.

Comment: `My code:` - what does your code do? What are those calculations about? `like the figure shown below.` - there is no figure in your question. `Sample Input Output` - please format your code correctly. I believe you meant to make a newline there. Help about [editing can be found here](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). `total area of A+B+C+D` - what is A B C and D?

Comment: what do you expect from output? are all length of rectangle equal?

Comment: Sir, Please check now.

Comment: But working for some test cases

Comment: my attempt: `scanf("%d",&test); for(i=0;i<test;i++) {scanf("%d",&n);printf("case %d: %d\n", i+1, 2*(n-2));}`

Comment: @MahfuzSaim: For what test cases is the program working? For what test cases is the program not working? What exactly does the online judge report? Where is the online judge?

Comment: Don’t calculate the areas A, B, C, D directly. Calculate the area of the big square, the four little squares (hint: their area is 1 each), and the four big triangles.  Half base times height.   Do some adding a subtracting; leave the maths library out of it. The instructions say the answer will always be an exact integer. Note that N must be at least three; two is a degenerate case (result zero).

Comment: Your code gives the [exact same answer as my](https://ideone.com/PuXdNJ) `2*(n-2)` for all `3<=n<=1018` ... Maybe try `printf("Case %d: %.0f\n", ...)` for C89 compatability (not `"%.0lf"`)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have a compatability problem and your online judge is on a C89 implementation where `"%lf"` does not exist, making your program output

```
Case 1: %.0lf
Case 2: %.0lf
...
```

Try using the C89 specifier

```
printf("Case %d: %.0f\n", i + 1, area - (area_t + 4));
/*               ^^^^ C89, not %.0lf                */
```

Note: `double x; scanf("&lf", &x)` has been valid since C89.

Answer (score -1):

Let `Area` be the requested area, which can be calculated as:

```
  Area = OuterSquareArea - 4 * IsoscelesTringleArea - 4 * SmallSqareArea
```

where:

```
           OuterSqareArea = n * n

    IsoscelesTriangleArea = base * height / 2
                          = (n - 2) * (n / 2) / 2
                          = (n - 2) *  n / 4

          SmallSquareArea = 1 * 1
                          = 1
```

The computation of `Area` can be summed up to:

```
    Area = (n * n) - 4 * ((n - 2)  * n / 4) - 4 * (1)
         =  n * n  -      (n - 2)  * n      - 4
         = (n      -      (n - 2)) * n      - 4
         =                     2   * n      - 4
```

The trace guarantees that `t`, `n` and `Area` are integers. The code we need is then:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int i, t, n;
    scanf("%d", &t); /* read t */
    for (i = 1; i <= t; i++) { /* for any i in [1,t] */
        scanf("%d", &n); /* read n */
        printf("Case %d: %d\n", i, 2 * n - 4); /* solve */
    }
}
```

The code could simply be extented to check `t` and `n` to be in the given ranges.

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also include an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are generally of higher quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.